# How to add values to DataFrame columns based on previous values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this kind of table:
person_in - unique id of each person
act_id - unique id of each activity that the person has done
act_date - the date of each activity
act_time - categorial feature that represents part of the day(1 is morning, 2 is noon, 3 is evening and 4 is night)
act_place - categorial feature that represent places

| person_id | act_id | act_date | act_time | act_place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 20422 | 12/01/2021 | 1 | 1 |
| 11111 | 20423 | 12/01/2021 | 3 | 1 |
| 11111 | 20424 | 12/02/2021 | 1 | 2 |
| 11112 | 20425 | 12/02/2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 11112 | 20426 | 12/02/2021 | 3 | 3 |
| 11113 | 20556 | 12/03/2021 | 1 | 2 |
| 11113 | 20557 | 12/03/2021 | 2 | 3 |
| 11113 | 20558 | 12/04/2021 | 1 | 3 |

I want to add new columns to the DataFrame that indicates if the person **already was** in each place, I tried to iterate over the DataFrame rows, but it does not seem like a good solution.
The new DataFrame should look like this:

| person_id | act_id | act_date | act_time | act_place | was_in_1 | was_in_2 | was_in_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 20422 | 12/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11111 | 20423 | 12/01/2021 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11111 | 20424 | 12/02/2021 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11112 | 20425 | 12/02/2021 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11112 | 20426 | 12/02/2021 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11113 | 20556 | 12/03/2021 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11113 | 20557 | 12/03/2021 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 11113 | 20558 | 12/04/2021 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
# if not sorted:
# df = df.sort_values(by=["person_id", "act_date"])

g = df.groupby("person_id")
for c in df["act_place"].unique():
    df["was_in_{}".format(c)] = g["act_place"].transform(
        lambda x: (x == c)
        .shift()
        .replace(False, np.nan)
        .ffill()
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
    )

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   person_id  act_id    act_date  act_time  act_place  was_in_1  was_in_2  was_in_3
0      11111   20422  12/01/2021         1          1         0         0         0
1      11111   20423  12/01/2021         3          1         1         0         0
2      11111   20424  12/02/2021         1          2         1         0         0
3      11112   20425  12/02/2021         2          1         0         0         0
4      11112   20426  12/02/2021         3          3         1         0         0
5      11113   20556  12/03/2021         1          2         0         0         0
6      11113   20557  12/03/2021         2          3         0         1         0
7      11113   20558  12/04/2021         1          3         0         1         1
```